# mvn clean install only builds parent module, child modules are not getting build in multi module maven project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

Below is the  project structure

```
parent
--pom.xml
    --child1
      --pom.xml
    --child2
      --pom.xml
```

When I do maven clean install,  maven  only scan parent pom and  only do build on parent pom which has no logic at all. Somehow Maven doesn't build Child1 and child 2.

Parent pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.demo.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>demo-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo-parent</name>
<description>demo</description>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <modules>
            <module>demo-child1</module>
            <module>demo-child2</module>           
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
//omit dependency
```

Child1

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.demo.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.demo.child1</groupId>
<artifactId>demo-child1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo.child1</name>
<description>demo.child1</description>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
//omit dependency
```

same for child2.

Maven build output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo-parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo-parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ littleluck-parent ---
[INFO] Installing D:\demo\demo-parent\pom.xml to ommit-user\.m2\repository\com\demo\parent\demo-parent\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\demo-parent-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.633 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-17T18:41:48-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I expected when I run maven clean install on parent pom.xml, maven should be able to scan both childs and make build, but currently it only make build on parent.

Need some  help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Maven is not seeing your `modules` directive, because the profile is not active. To run using a profile, give the profile an `id` and specify it on the command line, as follows:

```
mvn install -Pmy-profile
```

To add an `id`, update as follows:

```
<profile>
  <id>my-profile</id>
  <modules>
    <module>demo-child1</module>
    <module>demo-child2</module>
  </modules>
</profiles>
```

Another option is to mark the profile as the default, as follows:

```
<profile>
  <id>my-profile</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <modules>
    <module>demo-child1</module>
    <module>demo-child2</module>
  </modules>
</profiles>
```

This eliminates the need to specify a profile id at the command line.

However, unless there is a specific reason to define modules inside a profile, you should pull it out and declare them at the `project` level, as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.demo.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo-parent</name>
  <description>demo</description>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>demo-child1</module>
    <module>demo-child2</module>
  </modules>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: when I remove profile, I wlll get child doesn't exist error.   Child module D:\...\demo-child of D:\...\parent\pom.xml does not exist.

Comment: Are you running Maven from within the `parent` directory? There should be a POM in the parent directory and a POM in each sub-directory (of the parent) `demo-child1` and `demo-child2`. You might want to check for typos. Try using underscores such as `demo_child1`. Sometime the operating system and editor use different hypens (especially if you are using something as NotePad or similar app).

Comment: the artifact ID and folder name are different, when I make it same, everything works. LOL. No where says they must be same.

Comment: The `artifact-id` should be difference for each module; however, the `module` directive is a path to the module directory relative to the POM that includes it (though, it could contain a path to other locations -- it is just not a good idea); and hence, the string given by `module` must resolve to an existing directory.

Comment: yeah. Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: @gamewu Thank you. I wish you great success on your project.